# WCF consume Https service

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

Currently I consume third party Web Services in my application, the Web Services is 1 way SSL but after I consume the Services in my Visual Studio. At the Web.Config files binding services become no SSL it should download the Https but now is Http. Below are my Web Service. Anyone here. Please help. Thanks

```
http://ws2.oriongateway.com:22836/willani2/services/ogltngws (No way SSL)
https://ws2.oriongateway.com:22837/willani2/services/ogltngws (1 way SSL)
```

My app.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
            <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="FileLog"/>
                    <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                    <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="FileLog"
                 type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                 initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
            <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="OglTngWsSoap11Binding1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="OglTngWsSoap12Binding1">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://ws2.oriongateway.com:22836/willani2/services/ogltngws.OglTngWsHttpSoap12Endpoint/"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="OglTngWsSoap12Binding1"
                contract="aService.OglTngWsPortType" name="OglTngWsHttpSoap12Endpoint1" />
            <endpoint address="http://ws2.oriongateway.com:22836/willani2/services/ogltngws.OglTngWsHttpSoap11Endpoint/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OglTngWsSoap11Binding1"
                contract="aService.OglTngWsPortType" name="OglTngWsHttpSoap11Endpoint1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Any errors appear, or exceptions?

Comment: Could you show Web.config?

Comment: No error just automatically the service change to Http but original I want is Https.

Answer (score 0):

Try next changes:

```
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="OglTngWsSoap11Binding1" />
            <security mode="Transport"> // add security mode
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

Change endpoint address to https and don't forget change port as well:

```
            <endpoint address="https://ws2.oriongateway.com:22837/willani2/services/ogltngws.OglTngWsHttpSoap11Endpoint/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OglTngWsSoap11Binding1"
            contract="aService.OglTngWsPortType" name="OglTngWsHttpSoap11Endpoint1" />
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I got this error,The basicHttpBinding has invalid child element security

Comment: Try wshttpbinding instead

Comment: Wallstrider, Thanks It work like charm after I ignore the certificate error handler. Thanks a lot. :)